# Is there a more elegant/simpler way to use jquery .slideToggle on multiple hidden divs than my current code?

Tags: jquery, html, replace, slidetoggle

Here is a link to a working fiddle of what I am doing: https://jsfiddle.net/yfe7ky3x/

I am creating a simple portfolio website and I would like to have pictures, here represented by white background placeholder divs, that when clicked, expand a hidden div which will contain more information on the project.

**jQuery:**

```
        $(function () {

        $("#one, #hiddenone").click(function(){
            $("#hiddentwo, #hiddenthree, #hiddenfour, #hiddenfive, #hiddensix").slideUp("slow");
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $("#hiddenone").slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            return false;
        }); 

        $("#two, #hiddentwo").click(function(){
            $("#hiddenone, #hiddenthree, #hiddenfour, #hiddenfive, #hiddensix").slideUp("slow");
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $("#hiddentwo").slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            return false;
        }); 

        $("#three, #hiddenthree").click(function(){
            $("#hiddenone, #hiddentwo, #hiddenfour, #hiddenfive, #hiddensix").slideUp("slow");
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $("#hiddenthree").slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            return false;
        }); 

        $("#four, #hiddenfour").click(function(){
            $("#hiddenone, #hiddentwo, #hiddenthree, #hiddenfive, #hiddensix").slideUp("slow");
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $("#hiddenfour").slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            return false;
        }); 

        $("#five, #hiddenfive").click(function(){
            $("#hiddenone, #hiddentwo, #hiddenthree, #hiddenfour, #hiddensix").slideUp("slow");
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $("#hiddenfive").slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            return false;
        }); 

        $("#six, #hiddensix").click(function(){
            $("#hiddenone, #hiddentwo, #hiddenthree, #hiddenfour, #hiddenfive").slideUp("slow");
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $("#hiddensix").slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            return false;
        }); 

        });
```

This works fine, but I can't help but feel it's horribly inefficient. I have seen some similar jquery work, I do not understand how to apply it to my situation. Ideally, I would just have one hidden div, that I can replace with unique content depending on the project clicked.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question right, but instead of using id's, you could use classes, and then instead of using `$("#hiddenfour").slideToggle("slow");`, you could use `$(this).slideToggle("slow")`.

Comment: You can use class instead of id's..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've coded this solution. Some guys were faster, but some of the provided solutions will not correctly handle all of the situation (as from what I see on first look). Also the css is simplified.

```
$(function () {

    $(".project-content").click(function () {
        $(this).slideUp("slow");
        $('#projectsgrid').find('.project[data-target=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').removeClass('active');
        return false;
    });

    $(".project").click(function () {
        var target = $("#" + $(this).data('target'));
        $(".project-content").not(target).slideUp("slow");
        target.slideToggle("slow").toggleClass("active");
        $('.project').not(this).removeClass('active');
        return false;
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vladiks/1tdaqmv8/2/

Comment: Thank you. I was happy with EdenSource's answer, but with what I learned from that plus this response, I was able to simplify it even more.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, you could do something like this :
all pictures get the class `picture`, all hidden have the class `hiddenInfos`, and your pictures ids are `one`, `two` etc... and your hidden divs have ids `hidden_one`, `hidden_two` etc...

```
    $(".picture, .hiddenInfos").click(function(){
        // please add here some code to check if it is a hidden one, so you have to substring the id to only get the number...

        // here only works on pictures, not on hidden
        pictureNumber = $(this).getId();
        // do not slide up this hidden
        $("#hidden_"+$pictureNumber).removeClass("slideUp");
        // slide up all divs with the class slideUp
        $(".slideUp").slideUp("slow");
        // give back class to slide up on next click of other picture
        $("#hidden_"+$pictureNumber).addClass("slideUp");
        // do your other stuff
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $("#hidden_"+$pictureNumber).slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it with this code..

```
        $(function () {

            $('.project').on('click', function(){
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
                var currel = $( this ).attr('id') ;
                $('[id^=hidden]').slideUp("slow");
                $('[id=hidden'+ currel +']').slideDown("slow");
            });


        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mkdizajn/3smokyhe/

I linked on wrong link :)

https://jsfiddle.net/mkdizajn/yoou8kpv/

^ ==> selector starts with
$ ==> selectro ends with..

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here, but it's kind of working, so I will keep exploring with this. Thank you. Can you explain what's going on with the [id^=hidden] part?

Answer (score 0):

I just add a wrapper to the hidden divs, and add them a class :

```
$(function () {
    $("#projectsgrid div").click(function () {
        $('.active').slideUp("slow");
        if ($(this).index() != $("#projectHidden div.active").index()) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $("#projectHidden div").eq($(this).index()).slideToggle("slow").addClass("active");
        } else {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
        }
    })
    $(".hidden").click(function () {
        $(this).slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```

In the solution, I use `.index()` and `.eq()` in order to determine the link between the content and the button for click event, and to check if already opened content have to reopen on click on its button

---

You also can clear you css code this way :

```
.hidden{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

> [Live exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/3prh2eej/)

Comment: Wellcome. I believe there might be a clearest way to do combining this with what @oserk provided with `$('[id=hidden'+ currel +']')`